# How to check ranges of java versions in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript

I am stuck: how to check if a user has a specified java requirement? I need to find ranges (for instance java versions between 1.5.0_10 and 1.6.0_10). I am using javaDeploy.js from Oracle and using the versioncheck method but I can't figure what I need to pass inside the versionCheck method for ranges such as the example I provided.

Comment: So you want to only launch an application if it is between a range of versions? I checked http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deployingApplets Your interested in using the deployJava object to find the exact version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var lower = deployJava.versionCheck("1.5.0_10+"),
    higher = deployJava.versionCheck("1.6.0_10+")
if (lower && !higher) {
    // between 1.5.0_10 && 1.6.0_10
}
```

Reference:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/ensuringJRE.html

Comment: You can also make use of `deployJava.getJREs()` to get the version directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could also directly get the java version:

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
     var versions = deployJava.getJREs();
     alert(versions);
     if(versions>= "1.5.0" && versions<= "1.6.1")
     alert("correct version");   
</script>
```